# Getting python regexp for data

Tags: python, regex

I have tried finding a python regular expression to match the following lines, and and my interest being to extract the portion of each line between "|" and "." (preceding upx). 
My attempt was:

```
pattern=compile.re(re"^\S+\|(\S+).upx\.+")
```

But it did not work

My data:

```
UMM_189|XXYT9888_UMX_5711769.upx_OWED_786_bopsio_34527_sen_72.345615
AMW_126|7010.upx_XAWA01266525261
QEA_234|Serami_bolismun_milte_1_UMM1.upx_YU_168145
MMP_377|723C_UMM_5711781.upx_UXA_2_serax_78120_ser_23.26255277
```

My expected output:

```
XXYT9888_UMX_5711769
7010
Serami_bolismun_milte_1_UMM1
723C_UMM_5711781
```

Any better ideas please?

Comment: @iCodez,Thanks for spotting the error. Now corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that Regex is necessary here because your data is pretty ordered.  A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) will suffice:

```
>>> data = '''\
... UMM_189|XXYT9888_UMX_5711769.upx_OWED_786_bopsio_34527_sen_72.345615
... AMW_126|7010.upx_XAWA01266525261
... QEA_234|Serami_bolismun_milte_1_UMM1.upx_YU_168145
... MMP_377|723C_UMM_5711781.upx_UXA_2_serax_78120_ser_23.26255277
... '''
>>> [x.split('|', 1)[1].split('.upx', 1)[0] for x in data.splitlines()]
['XXYT9888_UMX_5711769', '7010', 'Serami_bolismun_milte_1_UMM1', '723C_UMM_5711781']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\|(.*?)\.',data)
['XXYT9888_UMX_5711769', '7010', 'Serami_bolismun_milte_1_UMM1', '723C_UMM_5711781']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
your_str = "UMM_189|XXYT9888_UMX_5711769.upx_OWED_786_bopsio_34527_sen_72.345615"
result = re.match(r'^[A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{3}\|(?P<id>[A-Za-z0-9_]*).upx*', your_str)
print result.group('id')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better

Answer (score 0):

You have the slash dot and dot backwards. Try 
    `pattern=compile.re(re"^\S+\|(\S+)\.upx.+")`